# Mongo "prealloc" files taking up room

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to free up some space on an Ubuntu server running Mongo. I've attached a new, empty 8GB volume, and have the room to move stuff around.

I have several large (1GB) files in /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc, is it safe to delete these or move them? If I can move them--can anyone give me a pointer on how to do this for Mongo?

Comment: I've already attached and mounted my new volume, just need to know about these preallocated chunks of space.

Comment: Realizing over a year later how naive "large" was, in reference to 1GB :/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So in theory, the `prealloc` files are preallocated journal files. This is opposed to *in use* journal files which have the format `j._X`, where `X` is a digit.

The goal here is to have "the next" file already allocated when the last file runs out of space. Pre-allocation is often much faster than on-demand allocation.

> is it safe to delete these or move them?

The answer you seek is in the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling+Administration+Notes#JournalingAdministrationNotes-PreallocFiles%28e.g.journal/prealloc.0%29). The docs there seem to provide the key answer to your question:

> prealloc files do not contain data, but are rather simply preallocated files that are ready to use that are truly preallocated by the file system (i.e. they are not "sparse"). It is thus safe to remove them, but if you restart mongod with journaling, it will create them again if they are missing.*

Comment: Ah, you are correct. What I did was delete those files (and freed up 3GB of room), then edited /etc/mongodb.conf and changed dbpath to the new mount location, and set nojournal = true, which "Disables write-ahead journaling." Now that I have enough space I can actually comment that out, and most likely will since it seems to be the safer bet. Thanks @GatesVP

Comment: Some caveats: 8GB is not considered a lot of space in MongoDB-land. That journaling mechanism was originally called "single-server durability" b/c MongoDB's default settings are very volatile. If you don't have journaling on (*the default in 2.0+*), then you'll want to consider having a replica set. Otherwise your data is very susceptible to corruption.

Comment: Ok I appreciate that. It's a dev server, so I'll make sure my production one has much more.

Comment: @jbnunn what is the difference between `nojournal = true` and `journal = false`?

Comment: @GatesVP Journaling is enabled by default on Ubuntu (and probably Debian) packages. In my opinion, disabling journaling is especially useful for local development environments with limited storage.

Answer (score 8):

Add "smallfiles=true" in the MongoDB configuration file.

Comment: This will cause MongoDB to use 128M prealloc files instead of 1GB, but does not seem to reduce total journal size.

Comment: If I set this option and restart mongodb, will the existing files be reduced?

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson, did you try a restart? Did the file size get reduced?

Comment: @Yahya I really don't remember but it was on a live server and the problem is gone so I believe yes. But I would for sure try it on a local computer to find out